# How to act upon user registration (onRegister)

Tags: yesod

I'd like to perform some actions when a new user registers to my Yesod app.

What is the way to hook into that event?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user registration process is performed by a `POST` request to your application, you can hook into handler function, that handles this request.

Assuming you use the usual scaffold layout, the info which function that is can be found in the file `config/routes`. The name convention is to prepend "post" to the name of the route (i.e.: `RegisterUserR` -> `postRegisterUserR`).

Comment: In the default scaffolded Yesod app I can only see `/auth   AuthR   Auth   getAuth` - do you mean that one?

Comment: No. That one handles authentication. You need to have specified the registration process somewhere.

Comment: The auth (+registration) by default is using BrowserId. I haven't added another registration handler